# manually adding ajax control toolkit cascading drop down

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

Visual Studio 2010, .NET Framework 4.0
Trying to manually add an AjaxControlToolkit CascadingDropDown extender to a webpage dynamically.
The web page has a placeholder.  When it posts back the controls are built dynamically and added to the placeholder.  I have regular ASP.NET drop down list boxes that I want to add CascadingDropDown extender to.

```
myCascadingDropDown = New AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown
myCascadingDropDown.ID = "cdd_" & myDisplayedField.ControlID
myCascadingDropDown.BehaviorID = "cdd_" & myDisplayedField.ControlID
myCascadingDropDown.TargetControlID = myDisplayedField.ControlID
myCascadingDropDown.Category = myDisplayedField.ControlID
myCascadingDropDown.PromptText = "Select " & aField.Caption
myCascadingDropDown.ServicePath = "CascadingDropDown.asmx"
myCascadingDropDown.ServiceMethod = "DropDownListBoxChanged"
myPanelForFields.Controls.Add(myCascadingDropDown)
```

The error is the last line where it is adding the CascadingDropDown. The error is:

> Value cannot be null.  Parameter `name`: No target control is set for the `CascadingDropDown` extender.

And if you look at the property TargetControl on myCascadingDropDown it is null (nothing).  But you can not set it (it is read only).  I assumed that since I set TargetControlID that ASP.NET would set TargetControl from the TargetControlID.

Any ideas or suggestions?

More complete exception:
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: No target control is set for the CascadingDropDown extender.
  ParamName=No target control is set for the CascadingDropDown extender.
  Source=AjaxControlToolkit
  StackTrace:
       at AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown.CascadingDropDown_ClientStateValuesLoaded(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.LoadClientStateValues()
       at AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderControlBase.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
       at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child)

**ANSWER in VB.NET:**

Yuriy Rozhovetskiy nailed it.  I am programming this application in vb.net so first I created a global variable (my functions in this class are shared/static):

```
Shared ControlToResolve As System.Web.UI.Control
```

Then the code I created was:

```
myCascadingDropDown = New AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown
myCascadingDropDown.ID = "cdd_" & myDisplayedField.ControlID
myCascadingDropDown.BehaviorID = "cdd_" & myDisplayedField.ControlID
myCascadingDropDown.TargetControlID = myDisplayedField.ControlID
myCascadingDropDown.Category = myDisplayedField.ControlID
myCascadingDropDown.PromptText = "Select " & aField.Caption
myCascadingDropDown.ServicePath = "CascadingDropDown.asmx"
myCascadingDropDown.ServiceMethod = "DropDownListBoxChanged"
ControlToResolve = myBSCComboBox
AddHandler myCascadingDropDown.ResolveControlID, AddressOf myCascadingDropDown_ResolveControlID
myPanelForFields.Controls.Add(myCascadingDropDown)
```

then the handler is:

```
Shared Sub myCascadingDropDown_ResolveControlID(sender As Object, e As ResolveControlEventArgs)
    e.Control = ControlToResolve
End Sub
```

I defined the TargetControl of the CascadingDropDown as "ControlToResolve".  I set ControlToResolve to the target Drop Down List Box before I add the CascadingDropDown to the panel holding the controls. When I add the CascadingDropDown, it calls the handler myCascadingDropDown_ResolveControlID which assigns the drop down list box to the CascadingDropDown.Target

My web service looks like:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
<System.Web.Services.WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
<System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
<ToolboxItem(False)> _
Public Class CascadingDropDown
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
    Public Function DropDownListBoxChanged(ByVal knownCategoryValues As String, ByVal category As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
    End Function
```

and it calls this web service with my ControlID every time I need values in one of the drop down list boxes.  BTW - using the ControlID I can tell which drop down list box wants data, if it is a parent or child drop down list box and can go get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two available solutions: first one is to place target control and extender in same naming container and the second is to subscribe on extender's `ResolveControlID` event and in this event handler set target control directly to eventArgs.Control property. C# code below:

```
myCascadingDropDown.ResolveControlID += myCascadingDropDown_ResolveControlID;

void myCascadingDropDown_ResolveControlID(object sender, ResolveControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control = myDisplayedField;
}
```

Comment: You are the man, or the woman, or the thumb, or whatever you are - you are it!  :-)  Seriously, Thanks